# UIDocumentPickerViewController which cloud service is selected by user?

Tags: swift, google-drive-api, swift4, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I want to select files from Google drive and One drive cloud services for that purpose I am using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

[image]

ex:

```
func didPressOneDriveChoose() {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [(kUTTypePDF as String), (kUTTypeJPEG as String), (kUTTypePNG as String)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.show(importMenu, sender: nil)
}
```

Recived callBack on delegate method:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]){

    var arrFiles = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
    for url in urls {
        // returns local document directory URL
        // needs original GoogleDrive or OneDrive URL
    }
}
```

but I want to know is there any way to get which cloud service is selected by the user and also I want original URL pointing to that URL? Currently, it returns local documents directory URL after downloading that file on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize as so:

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [(kUTTypePDF as String), (kUTTypeJPEG as String), (kUTTypePNG as String)], in: .import)
```

If you [read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker) on this particular picker mode `.import` it states:

> The URLs refer to a copy of the selected documents. These documents are temporary files. They remain available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, move these files to a permanent location inside your sandbox.

`.open` seems like it would fit your use case better.

> The URLs refer to the selected documents. The provided URLs are
>   security-scoped, referring to files outside your app’s sandbox. For
>   more about working with external, security-scoped URLs, see
>   Requirements.

But seeing as you are merely observing the url's to identify the service and not actually trying to manually access those documents, you shouldn't need to worry about breaking any requirements. So change the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` initialization to:

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [(kUTTypePDF as String), (kUTTypeJPEG as String), (kUTTypePNG as String)], in: .open)
```

And it should work!

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to know the cloud service (unless you start inferring it from the URL... bad idea) for privacy reasons. However, you can get the files from their original location, not copies, if you use the `open` mode instead of the `import` mode (`in: .open`). Warning, if you use the `open` mode, you start opening documents in place, so you need to use File Coordination appropriately.

Comment: unless you start inferring it from the URL... bad idea. Can you please explain it why It's a bad idea?

Comment: Because this is a private implementation detail and the URLs can change in future versions of iOS. Actually, I have just checked and it looks like the only thing you can get from the URL is a UUID, so it’s probably impossible already.

Comment: Thanks, It will help a lot.